Attempting to test my stellar contract but Keep getting _stellar_stellar_sdk__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Server is not a constructor
hello I deployed a contract on the testnet and I am trying to test it but keep getting this error 'ERROR
stellar_stellar_sdk__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_.Server is not a constructor
TypeError: stellar_stellar_sdk__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_.Server is not a constructor
at initiateEscrow (http://localhost:3000/main.3eb67b39c1e514e9029b.hot-update.js:44:20)'. and this is currently my file 'import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { isConnected, signTransaction } from '@stellar/freighter-api';
import * as StellarSdk from '@stellar/stellar-sdk'; // Import everything from Stellar SDK
const ESCROW_CONTRACT_ID = 'CBGEJFHGPHWGY4E64WMTH7FYJM7GVJYWIV6S4INCQT6VHK26I3VR7XEO';
const ContractInteraction = () => {
const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');
const [makerPublicKey, setMakerPublicKey] = useState('');
const [treasuryPublicKey, setTreasuryPublicKey] = useState('');
const [transactionResult, setTransactionResult] = useState(null);
async function initiateEscrow() {
if (!(await isConnected())) {
console.log('Freighter is not connected.');
return;
}
// Create an instance of the Stellar server
const server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');

try {
  // Load the source account
  const sourceAccount = await server.loadAccount(makerPublicKey);

  // Create a new transaction
  const transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(sourceAccount, {
    fee: StellarSdk.BASE_FEE,
    networkPassphrase: StellarSdk.Networks.TESTNET,
  })
    .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.invokeHostFunction({
      function: 'initiate_escrow',
      parameters: [
        { type: 'u128', value: amount },
        { type: 'address', value: makerPublicKey },
        { type: 'address', value: treasuryPublicKey },
      ],
      contractId: ESCROW_CONTRACT_ID,
    }))
    .setTimeout(30)
    .build();

  // Convert the transaction to XDR and sign it using Freighter
  const transactionXDR = transaction.toXDR();
  const signedXDR = await signTransaction(transactionXDR, StellarSdk.Networks.TESTNET);

  // Convert the signed XDR back to a transaction
  const tx = StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder.fromXDR(signedXDR, StellarSdk.Networks.TESTNET);
  
  // Submit the signed transaction to the Stellar network
  const result = await server.submitTransaction(tx);

  console.log('Escrow initiated successfully:', result);
  setTransactionResult(result);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error initiating escrow:', error);
}

}
return (

Initiate Escrow


Amount:
<input
type="number"
value={amount}
onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)}
/>




Maker Public Key:
<input
type="text"
value={makerPublicKey}
onChange={(e) => setMakerPublicKey(e.target.value)}
/>




Treasury Public Key:
<input
type="text"
value={treasuryPublicKey}
onChange={(e) => setTreasuryPublicKey(e.target.value)}
/>


Initiate Escrow
  {transactionResult && (
    <div>
      <h3>Transaction Successful!</h3>
      <p>Transaction Hash: {transactionResult.hash}</p>
    </div>
  )}
</div>

);
};
export default ContractInteraction;
'
